# asp.net inproc vs out of proc performance

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I'm considering moving our web app session storage from In Proc to State Server.  Can anybody give any figures as to the performance difference?

Comment: figures on what? you'll have to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you performance metrics but it won't be as fast as InProc session state due to certain overheads:

- Cross Process calls add overheads
- Objects have to be serialised and deserialised
- Some objects can't be serialised (XmlDocument for example or those that inherit from MarshalByRef)

That said your session state data will survive application pool and IIS resets which may be the reason you're considering changing.